# GtkTextView top/bottom margin?

Tags: gtk3, gtktextview

I would like to know the correct and generally accepted way of adding a top and bottom margin to a [`GtkTextView`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html) that is inside of a [`GtkScrolledWindow`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScrolledWindow.html).  There are functions to set the left and right margin, which I am using:

```
gtk_text_view_set_left_margin(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(editor_text_view), 2);
gtk_text_view_set_right_margin(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(editor_text_view), 2);
```

But I can't seem to find any documentation on top and bottom.  I've tried changing the border width of the `GtkTextView` with [`gtk_container_set_border_width`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-set-border-width) but the border is not painted with the background color of the `GtkTextView`.

Basically - what I have is on the left and what I want is on the right.

[image: Screenshot of what I have]   [image: Screenshot of what I want]

Comment: I doubt if `set_{left,right}_margin()` is what you want, as they can be overridden as the documentation states.  I wonder if the border background color can be made to match the text background?  FWIW, you can get the gdk windows associated with the four border areas (and set their widths individually), so maybe the colors can be made to match.

Comment: In 2022 you do have `top margin` and `bottom margin`: https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.TextView.set_top_margin.html https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.TextView.set_bottom_margin.html

Answer (score 4):

You should use CSS for this things in GTK+ 3:

http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.3/GtkCssProvider.html

Maybe you can use the [view class:](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.3/GtkStyleContext.html#GTK-STYLE-CLASS-VIEW%3aCAPS)

```
.view {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Or only apply the style to the GtkTextView:

```
GtkTextView {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure the padding property has any effect on the TextView

Comment: Since GtkAlignment has been deprecated since 3.14 this is probably the best way now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Ubuntu Natty with gtk+-3.2.3. and those CSS properties don't have any affect for some reason.

But you can use:
gtk_text_view_set_border_window_size( )

Along with: GTK_TEXT_WINDOW_TOP and GTK_TEXT_WINDOW_BOTTOM

And the border color will match the background of the GtkTextView.

http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkTextView.html#gtk-text-view-set-border-window-size

Comment: Sometimes this works, sometimes it doesn't. In my Ubuntu Mate virtual machine it does match the background, in my Fedora one it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to solve similar issue and I nested the text view in [GtkAlignment](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkAlignment.html) - that gave me an option to set padding for all sides.

Comment: But then you can't change border color when textview is in focus. :(